# Удаление столбца таблицы. Фильтр не работает

Tags: jquery

Не получается удалить столбец в таблице. Что делаю не так?

HTML - часть кода таблицы

```
<tr class="item">
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
     <td>242428810</td>
     <td>Евгений</td>
     <td>Архипов</td>
     <td>complectbannerov</td>
     <td>13</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

Пытаюсь использовать фильтр, но ни одна ячейка не удаляется.

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    $(this).filter("td:eq(2)").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td:eq(2)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr class="item">
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item">
     <td>242428810</td>
     <td>Евгений</td>
     <td>Архипов</td>
     <td>complectbannerov</td>
     <td>13</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! Могли бы Вы объяснить почему не работало с filter?

Comment: @ЕвгенийАрхипов `filter` - делает подвыборку из элементов той выборки, на которой он вызывается. В `$(this)` всего один элемент - `tr`.